# unable to find a substring in html after decode/normalize

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a snippet of html held as a string "s", it's user generated and may come from multiple sources, so I can't control the encoding of characters etc.

I have a simple string "comparison", and I need to check if comparison exists as a substring of "s". "comparison" does not have any html tags or encoding.

I am decoding, normalizing, and using a regex to strip out html tags, but am still unable to find the substring even when I know it is there...

```
string s = "<p>this is my string.</p><p>my string is html with tags and <a href=&quot;someurl&quot;>links</a>&nbsp;and&nbsp;encoding.</p><p>i want to&nbsp;find&nbsp;a&nbsp;substring but my comparison might not have tags &amp; encoding.";

    string comparison = "i want to find a substring";

    string decode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
    string tagsreplaced = Regex.Replace(decode, "<.*?>", " ");
    string normalized = tagsreplaced.Normalize();


    Literal1.Text = normalized;

    if (normalized.IndexOf(comparison) != -1)
    {
        Label1.Text = "substring found";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "substring not found";
    }
```

This is returning "substring not found". I can see by clicking view source that the string sent to the Literal **absolutely** includes the comparison string exactly as provided, so why isn't in being found?

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space and might be not be encoded to the "normal" space `' '` and therefore your comparision between the html-decoding of `i want to&nbsp;find&nbsp;a&nbsp;substring` and `i want to find a substring` might not match. Did you check the debugger that the html entities get correctly decoded? You can also dump the UTF-8 encoding (`Encodings.UTF8.GetBytes()`) to verify what the strings look like under the hood. (According to http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?htmlent=1 the non-breaking space has UTF8 encoding `0xc2 0xa0`, but a space is `0x20`)

Comment: The actual HTML probably has `"` instead of `&quot;`

Comment: i can see the source, that it is decoded to a single space. the page source has the string exactly as the comparison.

Comment: @Dave, can you show us an example of the input text that does not work, but should? Your `s` does not contain `comparison`, so it's really impossible to give you an answer as is.

Comment: @Rob sorry I don't understand, comparison is clearly in s, except for the &nbsp; bits (which Maximilian has explained). That's my exact issue - is there a way to compare html (inlcuding tags and encoding) to a string that doesn't have the tags and encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the HTML entity decoding still decodes your `&nbsp;` to the character `0xc2 0xa0` which is **not** a normal space character `' '` (which is `0x20`). Verfy this with the following program:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;

namespace TestStuff
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "<p>this is my string.</p><p>my string is html with tags and <a href=&quot;someurl&quot;>links</a>&nbsp;and&nbsp;encoding.</p><p>i want to&nbsp;find&nbsp;a&nbsp;substring but my comparison might not have tags &amp; encoding.";
            s = "i want to&nbsp;find&nbsp;a&nbsp;substring";

            string comparison = "i want to find a substring";

            string decode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s);
            string tagsreplaced = Regex.Replace(decode, "<.*?>", " ");
            string normalized = tagsreplaced.Normalize();

            Console.WriteLine("Dumping first string");
            Console.WriteLine(normalized);
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(normalized)));

            Console.WriteLine("Dumping second string");
            Console.WriteLine(comparison);
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(comparison)));

            if (normalized.IndexOf(comparison) != -1)
                Console.WriteLine("substring found");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("substring not found");

            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

It dumps the UTF8 encodings of the two strings for you. You'll see as output:

```
Dumping first string
i want to find a substring
69-20-77-61-6E-74-20-74-6F-C2-A0-66-69-6E-64-C2-A0-61-C2-A0-73-75-62-73-74-72-69-6E-67
Dumping second string
i want to find a substring
69-20-77-61-6E-74-20-74-6F-20-66-69-6E-64-20-61-20-73-75-62-73-74-72-69-6E-67
substring not found
```

You see that the bytearrays **do not** match, therefore they aren't equal, therefore `.IndexOf()` is right to tell you that nothing was found.

So, the problem lies within the HTML itself since there is a non-breaking space character which you don't decode to a normal space. You can hack around it by substituting a `"&nbsp;"` for a `" "` in the string using `String.Replace()`.

Comment: ok, thanks. So - is the only way around this, since I can't know in advance how the html is encoded, to find every possible encoding (not just spaces but all characters) and replace it?

Comment: The `.Normalize()` and `HtmlUtility.HtmlDecode()` does the most stuff for you, but unfortunetly, if the website decides to do such a thing as using a non-breakable space character, this screws up your code. You should thoroughly analyze from which website you're analyzing the html sourcecode and work around the common pitfalls (such as that space). But in general, I can't think of any more html-entities that decode to weird Unicode stuff and are widely used, so `&nbsp;` should hopefully be your only problem.

Comment: there are other ones too - basically anything in hex code e.g. &#x2013; so I guess I need to replace all of these? a bit of a pain as it will be slow, but if it works it's what I need.